# On wxpython, using Ctrl + A to select all items or select items using button

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

On wxpython, is there any way to select all items using `Ctrl + A` instead of clicking on the item itself one by one on the panel?

Or, if it is impossible, can we set a button that when it's clicked, all items in the `ListCtrl` will then be selected?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you have in the panel.
A menuitem can be assigned an `Accelerator` i.e. Ctrl+A then it's simply down to your ingenuity to create a function that is called when activated, to select whatever.

For your listctrl query, of course. You write a function, bound to the button, that makes use of the listctrls functions `Select()` and `GetItemCount()`.

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Select")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0
        self.text = "Timbuktoo"
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(750,350),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due', width=150)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=300)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Select All")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSelect)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        for i in range(10):
            self.add_line()

    def OnSelect(self,event):
        for i in range(self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()):
            self.list_ctrl.Select(i)

    def add_line(self):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 1, "12/06/2020")
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 2, self.text)
        self.index += 1
        self.text = self.text+"1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just as @[Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62341678/5133524) said, control + a can be achieved using wx.Accelerators, here is an example in python3 based on his code:

```py
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Select")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.text = "Timbuktoo"
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(750,350),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, 0, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        #add select all accelerator handler binded to OnSelectAll
        ID_SELECT_ALL=wx.NewIdRef(count=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSelectAll, id=ID_SELECT_ALL)

        self.SetAcceleratorTable(wx.AcceleratorTable([
            wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('A'), ID_SELECT_ALL)
        ]))

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due', width=150)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=300)

        for i in range(10):
            self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(i, f"Line {i}")
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(i, 1, "12/06/2020")
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(i, 2, self.text)
            self.text = self.text+"1"


    def OnSelectAll(self,event):
        for i in range(self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()):
            self.list_ctrl.Select(i)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Yes Giuliano, useful! I tend to forget about the `AcceleratorTable` because I prefer to have a visual hint in a menu or a button of some sort but of course, there are many ways to skin a cat, to use an old proverb.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony , true, i added this answer because i needed the keyboard shortcut in my app and all examples  i found were too old to use or didn't quite fit with ListCtrl + Accelerators, but thank you for the original answer, it guided me to the answer i needed :)

Comment: `GetItemCount` is now `GetCount`